# Autoquery servicestack ILeftJoin issue with table.id column

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery, autoquery-servicestack

I have definition of autoquery dto defined as below:

```
[Route("/project/{ProjectId}/contracts/{ContractId}/items")]
    public class QueryContractItem : QueryDb<ContractItem, ContractItemResponse>, 
        ILeftJoin<ContractItem, ContractItemEstimateItem>, 
        ILeftJoin<ContractItemEstimateItem, EstimateItem>,
        ILeftJoin<ContractItemEstimateItem, ContractItemEstimateItemComponent>,
        ILeftJoin<EstimateItem, EstimateComponent>,
        ILeftJoin<EstimateItem, EstimateGroup>
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
    }





      public class ContractItemResponse
       {
// ...
        public int ContractItemEstimateItemId { get; set; } // WRONGLY taken from ContractItemEstimateItemComponent.ContractItemEstimateItemId - PROBLEM
        public int ContractItemEstimateItemEstimateItemId { get; set; } //value is taken correctly from ContractItemEstimateItem - CORRECT
        public int ContractItemEstimateItemContractItemId { get; set; } //value is taken correctly from ContractItemEstimateItem - CORRECT
    
       }
```

Not sure why during query execution  the value of ContractItemEstimateItemId is taken from ContractItemEstimateItemComponent.ContractItemEstimateItemId (the value is not yet there).

Expected is that query will take a value for field `ContractItemEstimateItemId` from `ContractItemEstimateItem.Id`